# How to test a function that returns a nested map?

Tags: unit-testing, clojure

If a function say, `(get-user-details user-id)` returns a nested map like:

```
 {:first-name "John"
  :last-name "Doe"
  :age 24
  :address {:house-no "24/3" 
            :street "Peter Parker Street"
            :city "New York"
            :country "USA"}}
```

How should I test it ?

the order matters with = operator, and I don't want the order or existence of certain extra keys to matter the passing of the test case.

What is a general testing strategy for such cases?

Comment: In maps, order does not matter. Maps' notion of equivalence, as invoked by `=`, is that they have the same number of elements and that all the key/value pairs of one are in and the same the other.

Comment: As to extra keys, I don't see how this happens if you are mocking data, but you'd need a recursive submap.

Comment: you can check if required keys are in map using sets: `(subset? (set [:first-name]) (set (keys {:first "John"}))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At work we use some rather large nested maps and we use [Prismatic's Schema library](https://github.com/prismatic/schema) both to test the structure and to describe their structure to other humans. It handles things like optional keys well and the definitions compose nicely to keep things readable.

here is a sample from their site:

```
(s/validate
  Data  
  {:a {:b 123
       :c "ABC"}})
;; Exception -- Value does not match schema:
;;  {:a {:b (not (instance? java.lang.String 123)),
;;       :c (not (integer? "ABC"))}, 
;;   :d missing-required-key}
```

After verifying the structure of the data I tend to use `get-in` and `select-keys` to test specific values within the larger nested structure. With one assertion per logical chunk of the map so the errors are meaningful when things break.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function like this:

```
(defn my-eq [expected actual]
  (let [actual-subset (select-keys actual (keys expected))]
    (= actual-subset expected)))
```

It selects the keys from your actual result based on the keys in the expected hash, then compares them.

**EDIT**

However, I rarely write a *test* like this. Instead, I prefer to break each thing out into separate tests so that the error messages provide meaningful feedback:

```
(is (= "Donna" (:name actual)))
(is (= 23 (:age actual)))
(let [address (:address actual)]
  (is (= 90210 (:zip address))))
```